# Checking if jQuery's $.post() failed due to lost connection

Tags: post, jquery

I do a bunch of $.post()'s in my script, within a $(document).ready(function(){

jQuery says:

> If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError() method.

I tried adding this as a first test

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
alert('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \\n'+'error:\\n' + exception);
});
```

But it failed to do anything. Can anyone assist? I just need to popup an alert if the internet connection is lost. I also tried using window.navigator.onLine for this but it's not supported in Safari

Answer (score 0):

have you tried not binding it to document?

```
$('.log').ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
   alert('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \\n'+'error:\\n' + exception);
});
```

Comment: It should work the same either way, the event is fired for all elements bound to it...jQuery crawls the `$.cache` object to check which ones to fire it on.

Answer (score 0):

woops, looks like i managed to loose my association with the original post - i made this post.

Anyway to clarify, the code I have is:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 

$(this).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
    alert('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \\n'+'error:\\n' + exception);
});

$.post("dostuf.php", { action: "thething"  });
```

No error is being thrown.

Comment: Your username and userid appear to have changed. Weird.

Comment: @Keyo, @BoltClock - He's logged in with *another* OpenID

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on .post(); but in the api for .ajax() there is an error function you can pass to the object.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"http://yourwebservice.com/get_data",
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        //do stuff 
        alert('fail whale');
    },
    success:function(data) {
        alert('it worked!');
    }        
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

By the way, welcome to stackoverflow!